how to I pass variables in wordpress
I have a form. Simplified it looks like this:
<form action="https://www.example.com/url.php" method="post" name="Go" id="Go">
<input name="Go" type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>

The page that the form submits to is the same as itself ie https://www.example.com/url.php is the form that the page is on. The page also has other forms on it.
When a form on this page is submitted, I use
if (isset($_REQUEST['Go'])) {}
to check if that form was submitted and then carry out actions.
This works just fine, except when I try and do the same thing by inserting the code into a WordPress page and change the action address of the form to https://www.example.com/permalink which is the permalink URL of the page that I've inserted the code into. The page no longer seems to get the $_REQUEST. Is WordPress blocking this global variable and if so what is the best workaround?
Tried everything with no luck

How are you putting this form on that page? Are you using a template or a shortcode? Also, make sure you checkout developer tools to make sure a redirect isn't happening after the POST.

I'm inserting the php code with a plugin.
Seems that WP doesn't allow global variables. Made a workaround with a hidden field in the form.
